# How to run Java programs from Algorithms textbook by Robert Sedgewick?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

I apologize for a rookie question.  I am trying to run the Java programs in Eclipse given in the Algorithms, 4th edition book by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/

I am having trouble with input arguments to the programs.

For example for the following program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch
{
    public static int rank(int key, int[] a)
    { // Array must be sorted.
     int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi)
        { // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.

          int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] whitelist = In.readInts(args[0]);
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        { // Read key, print if not in whitelist.        
         int key = StdIn.readInt();
            if (rank(key, whitelist) < 0)
            StdOut.println(key);
        }    
    }
}
```

The input arguments are:

```
% java BinarySearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt
```

I don't know where to pass input arguments in Eclipse. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Go to Run->Run As-> Run configuration ... there you will see Command line arguments text box where you can add the arguments

Comment: `int key = StdIn.readInt();` This will not work. Unless you use the `lib`.

Comment: Since your program relies on redirection, you'll have to open a cmd  window and run Java from the command line. IDEs do not support file redirection.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I tried in cmd. But it throws an error. The "<" in the command is interfering somehow.

Comment: Then add the error to your question, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in "Run configuration..." opening the menu of the play button.
[image: Picture]

You find what you need in arguments, environment tab and common.
Actually common is the tab that you need.

Comment: This wouldn't help with the file redirection in the OP's command line.

Comment: It should, see https://www.eclipse.org/mars/noteworthy/#_assigning_stdin_to_a_file On the Common tab, check "Input file" and select tinyT.txt

Comment: I wrote it. I posted the main dialog, but I also wrote down that the tab common is what he needs exactly for this. But in general around it he can find everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone!
I solved it. Apparently the newer libraries provided on the book site vary a bit from the book that I have.

I changed the main function as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class BinarySearch{
public static int rank(int key, int[] a)
{ // Array must be sorted.
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = a.length - 1;
    while (lo <= hi)
    { // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
        else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
        else return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    In i = new In(args[0]);
    In j = new In(args[1]);
    int[] whitelist = i.readAllInts();
    int[] iplist = j.readAllInts();
    Arrays.sort(whitelist);
    for (int key:iplist)
    { // Read key, print if not in whitelist.
        if (rank(key, whitelist) < 0)
        StdOut.println(key);
    }
}
}
```

Then pass

```
"tinyW.txt" "tinyT.txt"
```

as Program arguments as indicated by @GDG612 .

Answer (score 1):

i'm put everything in one folder just to sure everything could run.

tools:
vscode without plugin
jdk 17

import dependencies into BinarySearch.java:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In; 
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;  
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
```

```
compile:  
javac -cp algs4.jar: BinarySearch.java   
java -cp algs4.jar: BinarySearch tinyAllowlist.txt < tinyText.txt
```

based on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSso2-eRa1w
in java 17 you didn't have to use javac

so it is just like this

```
java -cp algs4.jar BinarySearch.java tinyAllowlist.txt < tinyText.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your program and select `Run As -> Run Configurations...`
Then click on `(x)= Arguments` tab and pass the inputs to the program under `Program arguments`

Comment: What about the file redirection?